# Bad shading in blender

Tags: 3d, blender, shading

`The problem with shading.

P.S. All normals are turned correctly, applied shade smooth and auto smooth. Polygons lie in one plane.


[shading problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBlCL.png)

[topology and normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmSNI.png)

[All on 1 plane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKjRc.png)

I've already tried changing the topology (tris, quads), adding the "weighted normals" modifier.`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked in [blender.se].

Answer (score 0):

It is a topology issue I believe.
See my images for how I created it. It is more mesh dense but that can be reduced a bit more, especially along the length.

[Edit Mode Topology View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j98Hj.jpg)
[Viewport MatCap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1nZ4.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).